# Separate mysql query on the phpbb3 forums returning nothing (mysql on the server but its not being used by phpbb)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-connection, phpbb3

So i entered few quotes on a database and i wanted to display it on a footer block of my phpbb3 forums page.

I created a file for the database connection and query called "ligacao.php":

```
                                <?php
$ligacao = new mysqli("localhost","starwmjz_mike","PASSWORD","starwmjz_pallet");


if($ligacao->connect_error){
    die("Error:" . $ligacao->connect_errno . "," . $ligacao->connect_error);
}

$ligacao->set_charset("utf8");

$tipQuery = $ligacao->query("SELECT tipQuote FROM tips ORDER BY rand() limit 1");           
?>
```

And on the footer block i added these lines:

```
<div id="col1">
    <!-- Column one content beginning -->
    <!-- INCLUDEPHP http://pallet-town.net/backend/ligacao.php -->
    <!-- PHP -->
    echo $tipQuery;
    <!-- ENDPHP -->
    <!-- Column one content end -->
</div>
```

The mysql is on the same server but its not being using by phpbb in any other instance

The query works just fine as i tested it before using it.
The result is an empty footer block so far.
I've enabled php on the acp.
All help and suggestions are welcome, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the answer, if anyone else has the same problem this worked for me:

```
$result = mysqli_query($ligacao,"SELECT * FROM YOUR-TABLE-NAMe ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['YOUR-ROW-NAME'];

}
mysqli_close($ligacao);
```

So in order to access an exterior mysql you need a single PHP file on the root folder of the forums.
To include in on your code, just add `<!-- INCLUDEPHP YOUR-FILE.php -->`to where you'll want the the information to be inserted.

In this particular case the final php file code is:

```
<?php

$ligacao = new mysqli("YOUR-HOST","DATABASE-USER","PASSWORD","DATABASE-NAME");


if($ligacao->connect_error){
    die("Error:" . $ligacao->connect_errno . "," . $ligacao->connect_error);
}

$ligacao->set_charset("utf8");


$result = mysqli_query($ligacao,"SELECT * FROM YOUR-TABLE-NAME ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");                               
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo $row['YOUR-ROW-NAME'];
}

mysqli_close($ligacao);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing query execute statment and your code should be look like below :

```html
<?php
$ligacao = new mysqli("localhost","starwmjz_mike","PASSWORD","starwmjz_pallet");


if($ligacao->connect_error){
    die("Error:" . $ligacao->connect_errno . "," . $ligacao->connect_error);
}

$ligacao->set_charset("utf8");

$tipQuery = $ligacao->query("SELECT tipQuote FROM tips ORDER BY rand() limit 1"); 
?>

<div id="col1">
    <!-- Column one content beginning -->
    <!-- INCLUDEPHP http://pallet-town.net/backend/ligacao.php -->
    <!-- PHP -->
    while ($obj=$ligacao->fetch_object($tipQuery))
    {
        printf("%s \n",$obj->tipQuote);
    }        
    <!-- ENDPHP -->
    <!-- Column one content end -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance but it does not seem to be working :(

Comment: then do one thing just add print_r($row); instead of echo $row[0]['tipQuote']; and see what is it return???

Comment: not on the forums, i just get a empty div but i just noticed an error on the ligacao.php, check this link: http://pallet-town.net/backend/ligacao.php

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, but i appreciate the help:)

Comment: this is the error on the forum div:Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in /home/starwmjz/public_html/sites/pixel/forums/cache/tpl_Metro Teal_prefooter_blocks.html.php on line 11

Comment: I think the problem with mysqli...may be phpbb don't allow our query.

Answer (score 0):

You miss one step before echoing query result. 
Try it like this :

```
<?php
$ligacao = new mysqli("localhost","starwmjz_mike","PASSWORD","starwmjz_pallet");


if($ligacao->connect_error){
    die("Error:" . $ligacao->connect_errno . "," . $ligacao->connect_error);
}

$ligacao->set_charset("utf8");

$tipQuery = $ligacao->query("SELECT tipQuote FROM tips ORDER BY rand() limit 1"); 
$obj = $ligacao->fetch_object($tipQuery);  
?>

<div id="col1">
    <!-- Column one content beginning -->
    <!-- INCLUDEPHP http://pallet-town.net/backend/ligacao.php -->
    <!-- PHP -->
    echo $obj->tipQuote;
    <!-- ENDPHP -->
    <!-- Column one content end -->
</div>
```